# How to create the object in objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two .m file one is masterdetail.m and detailview.m  here i have to create the object of the detailview.m in masterdetail.m  how it write??

Comment: i think you could find answer in google in few seconds but if it's difficult for you somehow - DetailView *detailView = [[DetailView alloc] init];

Comment: You're going to need to take some time to learn Objective-C.  This is a fundamental question; if you can't do this then you won't progress very far at all.

Comment: @user1556719 I learned Objective-C using the Apple docs and OSX/iOS programming from both Apple's docs and books.

Comment: This is not a real Question ... use Google :) thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

First add `#import  "detailview.h"` statement in `masterdetail.m`

and write Following code  in (*relavant place of*) `masterdetail.m`

```
detailview *myObj =[[detailview alloc] init];
```

here  `myObj` is object of `detailview` and it use as per your requirement.

For more information [Refere This Official Document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html)